# How to check element loaded in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I want to get the height of `divArea` and store it in the `scrollTop` variable.
However, When I initialize `scrollTop` to `this.divArea.nativeElement.offsetHeight` in onInit function, an error occurred.
The error is that `divArea` is null.
One workaround is to use `setTimeout().`
But I do not want to use `settimeout()`.
How to solve this problem?

#### html

```
<div #divarea>
  <p>Hello1</p>
  <p>Hello1</p>
  <p>Hello1</p>
  <p>Hello1</p>
</div>
<div [style.top.px]="scrollTop">
  ...
</div>
```

#### ts

```
export class test implements OnInit {
  public scrollTop: number;
  @ViewChild('divarea') private divArea: ElementRef;
  public ngOnInit() {
    this.scrollTop = this.divArea.nativeElement.offsetHeight; // result: error
  }
}
```

Comment: Use 'ngAfterViewInit' instead

Comment: I would use the following https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705390/11135174

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.scrollTop = this.divArea.nativeElement.offsetHeight; // result: error
  }
```

- You Local variable `(#divArea)` will be available to use within the `ngAfterViewInit` hook of angular.
- Also `@View Child` should be `@ViewChild` without any space between.
- `<div #divarea">` should be `<div #divarea>`

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/scroll-local-variable?file=src/app/app.component.html)