# How to programmatically click through a list of elements if one has to wait for a click to load a set of predefined new elements?

Tags: javascript

For example, I would like to download the old-time radio show [I Love a Mystery](https://www.otrr.org/OTRRLibrary/otrrlibrary.html?idp=4919) from the OTRR website. I figured out how to construct the list of right URLs,

```js
const urlStub = "https://otrr.org/OTRRLibrary/jukebox/";
copy(Array.from(
    document.getElementsByTagName('a')).
        map( a => `"${urlStub}${a.href.split('/').pop()}"` ).
        join(' ')
)
```

but when I call it with `curl`,

```bash
for url in <copied-list>; do curl -k -O $u; done
```

I get a lot of `404 Not Found`. I realized that clicking on the titles will load a player on the page "pre-loading" the audio file, and then I can use `curl`. It is quite a chore to go through hundreds of files though, so I figured I would make it a bit easier by collecting the "title" elements, and click them one by one until it errors out,

```js
const t = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td.colTitle'));

t.pop().click()
...
t.pop().click()
```

but this is still not the best.

---

I provided a solution below that uses [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) recursively, but not sure if there would something simpler (and one that doesn't potentially crash on a page with thousands of episodes).

Answer (score 0):

I cobbled together the snippet below from the SO threads

- [javascript - How to wait until an element exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists)
- [javascript - How to check if an element has been loaded on a page before running a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34863788/how-to-check-if-an-element-has-been-loaded-on-a-page-before-running-a-script)

and it seems to get to job done, but the `Promise` will always remain `pending` and it is pretty much just a hack.

```js
function waitForElement(querySelector, elemArr) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
        if (elemArr.length) {
            console.log(elemArr);
            elemArr.pop().click();
        } else {
            return resolve();
        }
    
        if (document.querySelectorAll(querySelector).length) {
            waitForElement(querySelector, elemArr);
        }
    
        const observer = new MutationObserver( () => {
            if (document.querySelectorAll(querySelector).length) {
                observer.disconnect();
                waitForElement(querySelector, elemArr);
            }
        });
      
        observer.observe(document.body, {
            childList: true, 
            subtree: true
        });
    });
}

t = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td.colTitle'))

waitForElement("audio", t)
```